# Changing the volume leads to frame drop

Tags: javascript, svelte, hls.js

I am using and learning Svelte. So I am creating a video player with help of hls.js library (because I did not found any readymade video players which worked properly and had the functionality I wanted). When I try to change the volume of the video, frame drop occurs.

```
function handleVolume(event) {
    volume = event.target.value;
    if (volume === 0) { isMuted = true; }
   else { isMuted = false; }
}

function debounce(func, delay) {
    let timeoutId;
    return function (...args) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(this, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}

function updateVideoVolume() {
    video.volume = volume / maxVolume;
}

const updateVideoVolumeDebounced = debounce(updateVideoVolume, 200);

onMount(() => {
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        hls = new Hls();
        let src = 'http://localhost:3000/videos/video3';
        hls.loadSource(src);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.enableWorker = true;
        duration = video.duration;

        hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {});
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
            console.log(data.levels);
            for (let i = 0; i < data.levels.length; i++) {
                resolutions = [...resolutions, [data.levels[i].height, data.levels[i].bitrate]];
            }
            console.log(resolutions);
        });
    }
});
</script>

<input
    type="range"
    on:input={handleVolume}
    on:change={updateVideoVolumeDebounced}
    id="volume"
    name="volume"
    min="0"
    max={maxVolume}
/>
```

It happens with both `on:change` and `on:input` when using the range input element. I also tried to debounce the `handleVolume` but then the frame drop occurs after the delay. I have also tested it on different browsers. In Firefox, the frame drop is less. Meanwhile in Brave, it is similar. I guess this is because of Chromium.

Comment: Hey Syko, Svelte questions are way easier to answer if you show us enough code to reproduce it. Can you create a [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/)?

Comment: @ChrisPfohl Sure, here is the code https://svelte.dev/repl/1697da53c0db40d288cba092293c887c?version=3.59.1
When you open the repl and once you see the controls, click play and everything will look normal

Comment: In the future, create a ***minimal*** example first and include everything directly in the question.

Comment: Understood. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question is mostly irrelevant.

You have a binding on `video` that gets and sets `currentTime`, the bound variable (`playbackTime`) is reactive with a dependency on `video`.

```js
$: playbackTime = video ? video.currentTime : 0;
```

```html
<video ...
    bind:currentTime={playbackTime} />
```

The volume change has an assignment to a property of `video`, thereby invalidating `video`. This in turn will update `playbackTime` which sets the video's `currentTime`, causing a jitter.

Would recommend limiting the use of reactive statement, don't see much point in `playbackTime` being one either, just initialize to `0` and maybe update once in `onMount` or on some other events.

```js
let playbackTime = 0;
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. playbackTime been dependent on video was indeed the cause.